# Why are the bounds not working on this GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

Why are the bounds on the panelFirst not working? It just displays everything at the top and it does not display the bounds in the order I have set them? The radio buttons should display in one under the other and the next button should display on the far right but it is not working?

```
    public MyWizard() {
        panelContainer.setLayout(c1);
        panelFirst.add(btNext);
        panelSecond.add(btNextTwo);
        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panelThird.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panelContainer.add(panelFirst, "1");
        panelContainer.add(panelSecond,"2");
        panelContainer.add(panelThird,"3");
        c1.show(panelContainer, "1");           
        btNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(panelContainer,"2");                    
            }               
        });

        btNextTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(panelContainer,"3");                    
            }               
        });
        RadioButtons();
        Button();
        frame.add(panelContainer);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(600,360);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void RadioButtons() {
        btLdap = new JRadioButton ("Ldap");
        btLdap.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
        panelFirst.add(btLdap);         
        btKerbegos = new JRadioButton ("Kerbegos");
        btKerbegos.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
        panelFirst.add(btKerbegos);         
        btSpnego =new JRadioButton("Spnego");
        btSpnego.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
        panelFirst.add(btSpnego);
                    btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
        btSaml2.setBounds(60,175,100,20);
        panelFirst.add(btSaml2);
    }

    public void Button() {
        btNext.setBounds(400,260,100,20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyWizard();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: cause you are using a `LayoutManager`

Comment: how do I fix that? If I take the .setLayout out then the whole thing does not work

Comment: I get this error If I take that out Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout

Comment: you should use `LayoutManager` for many reasons, by default a panel has `FlowLayout`  to `setBounds` you have to `setLayout(null)` but it's stronly discourage

Comment: panelContainer.setLayout(null); I did like that, but I get this exception xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
 at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
 at MyWizard.<init>(MyWizard.java:31)
 at MyWizard$3.run(MyWizard.java:87)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)

Comment: follow @MadProgrammer advice, he is right.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `panelFirst` is (or extends from) something like `JPanel`, it will be under the control of a layout manager (in this case, most likely a `FlowLayout`).

It is highly recommended that you avoid `setBounds`, `setLocation` and `setSize` and instead rely on the layout managers

Graphical Interfaces are required to run on a variety of different platforms, each with unique rendering properties.  To solve this issue, the developers of Java/Swing/AWT designed the `LayoutManager` API.  This makes it easier to develop sophisticated user interfaces that will work on multiple different platforms

Take a look at [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your  radio buttons should be under each other, then create a panel for them, and set the panel's layout to `BoxLayout` like this:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

p.add(...);
//then add p to the fram's container or to some other container
```